# Change user profile sub type with powershell

Tags: powershell, user-profile-service, administration

How to change the user profile sub type for an account with powershell?

The UI way:

- Edit user profile in the CA.
- Change the subtype to custom subtype and save

So far I have this code.

```
$site = Get-SPSite -Identity http://www.mysharepoint.com/sites/sitename
$serviceContext = Get-SPServiceContext $site
$upm = new-object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($serviceContext)
$userProfile = $upm.GetUserProfile("domain\account");
$psm = [Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfileSubtypeManager]::Get($serviceContext);
$customprofilesubtype = $psm.GetProfileSubtype("custom subtype")
$userProfile.ProfileSubtype = $customprofilesubtype;
$userProfile.Commit();
```

-> Unfortunately nothing has been changed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's a bug. The commands are actually correct.

When I changed a user property, changes were saved.

I ended up changing a dummy property in order to save the custom profile subtype.

```
$site = Get-SPSite -Identity http://www.mysharepoint.com/sites/sitename
$serviceContext = Get-SPServiceContext $site
$upm = new-object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($serviceContext)
$userProfile = $upm.GetUserProfile("domain\account");
$userProfile["Dummy Property"].value = "Dummy Text";
$psm = [Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfileSubtypeManager]::Get($serviceContext);
$customprofilesubtype = $psm.GetProfileSubtype("custom subtype")
$userProfile.ProfileSubtype = $customprofilesubtype;
$userProfile.Commit();
```